# Can't see results of TestNG run in eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, groovy, testng

Using http://beust.com/eclipse TestNG plugin, I'm trying to run a TestNG suite within eclipse.

I have this testng.xml defined.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="1" name="Suite" parallel="methods" junit="true">
  <test name="Whatever">
  <classes>
  <class name="com.whatever.SomeTest" />
  </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

The `SomeTest` is a **groovy** junit test class with one public test method defined:

```
public class SomeTest extends Specification  {
    @Test    
    public void ShouldDoSomething() {
       when: "Something"
       then: "Assert"
       assert 1 == 2
    }
}
```

When I run the suite with plugin (Run as TestNG Suite), I don't see the results. The "Results of running suite" view says: Tests: 1/1 Methods: 0. I know that the method was actually run, I just don't get the result.

EDIT: I can see the results in Console like this, it just doesn't get to report.

```
Condition not satisfied:

1 == 2
  |
  false

    at org.spockframework.runtime.SpockRuntime.verifyCondition(SpockRuntime.java:36)
        ....
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
        ....
        at org.testng.junit.JUnit4TestRunner.start(JUnit4TestRunner.java:81)
```

This is what's outputed into testng-results.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testng-results skipped="0" failed="0" total="0" passed="0">
  <reporter-output>
  </reporter-output>
  <suite name="Suite" duration-ms="12406" started-at="2013-12-11T10:12:07Z" finished-at="2013-12-11T10:12:19Z">
    <groups>
    </groups>
    <test name="SomeTest" duration-ms="12406" started-at="2013-12-11T10:12:07Z" finished-at="2013-12-11T10:12:19Z">
    </test> <!-- SomeTest -->
  </suite> <!-- Suite -->
</testng-results>
```

What should I do to get the results?

Comment: Is that a [spock](https://code.google.com/p/spock/wiki/SpockBasics) formatted test you're trying to run?  And (I may be wrong, but) isn't the [annotation `@Test`](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/Test.html), not `@UnitTest`?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, the `@UnitTest` should not be there. It doesn't make any difference if I add either `@org.testng.annotations.Test` or `@org.junit.Test` annotation though. And yes, it's a spock formatted test.

Comment: spock tests should extend Specification, and [I don't believe they play well](https://code.google.com/p/spock/issues/detail?id=267) with testng

Comment: But the test is actually being run (yes it extends some specification), results are shown in console, they just don't get to report.

Comment: The test is being run. but not the method by the looks of the ouput

Comment: The method is run too, I can see the assert result in console.

Comment: What assert? Maybe if you edit your example code to accurately reflect the code you're running, someone might spot the problem?

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this issue (I am facing the same problem!)  Thanks

Comment: @JoeG: No, sorry, I wasn't. We have moved away from TestNG.